# Is there a way to expand a summation of product of two functions?

Tags: summation, summation-method

I have been experimenting with summations were you multiply to functions, e.g.
$\sum_{i=0}^n f(n)g(n)$ where $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=-\frac{x^2}{\log{x}}$. While trying out different functions for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, I stumbled upon this. $$\sum_{i=1}^n ((-1)^i\left|i+x-\frac{n}{2}\right|+\frac{1}{2})$$
I simplified it until here $$(\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i\left|i+x-\frac{n}{2}\right|\bigr)+\frac{n}{2}$$
I think I can simplify it more by making it so that in $\sum_{i=1}^nf(x)g(x), f(x)=(-1)^i$ and $g(x)=\left|i+x-\frac{n}{2}\right|$ and then expanding the summation, but I don't know how.

Is there a formula that expands out or simplifies $\sum_{i=1}^n f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: Do you know about [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)? You can also expand $f(x)$ into a series, switch both sums if possible, and calculate the inner sum to get one sum again.

Comment: For your particular example, I suggest breaking into 3 cases, depending on $x$: (1) $1+x \ge \frac n2$ (2) $\frac n2 + x \le 0$ and (3) the rest. For the latter, break the summation in two: $\sum_{i < x - n/2} + \sum_{i \ge x - n/2}$, I also suggest breaking up the summations into sums over odd $i$ and even $i$.

Comment: There is no formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$ in terms of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$